# VS2017 always change file symbol to warning after edit content inside

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've already update to the latest version, but it still have this issue.

`Visual Studio Community 2017 
Version. 15.3.4`

[image]

Comment: check in startup.cs file if it is found:   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json"). If not found please add it

Comment: Run Visual Studio 2017 as "run as Administrator". It will fix this issue

Comment: @AbhayDixit Although I try with `run as Administrator` it still not work. and this was happen all file in solution.

Comment: Are you creating a new project, or loaded any existing project>

Comment: Create a new project.

Comment: type Ctrl + W, E and check what is warning message, might be some reference warning is causing this